# Reading the url from the browsers address bar using C# and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use domain masking to simulate multi-tenant access to my application. The plan right now is to read the subdomain portion of the domain ie: demo.mydomain.com and load settings from the DB using that name.

The issue I'm having is that request.url is getting the request url - NOT the url in the browser.

So if I have http://demo.mydomain.com forwarding to http://www.mydomain.com/controllername with masking, request.url is grabbing the latter, simply because of how masking works, i assume - by putting the masked site inside of a frame.

Is it even possible to read the url in the browsers address bar? Thanks.

Comment: What standard guarantees that a browser has an address bar?

Comment: Lets go with the assumption that our users will be using Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari or Chrome.

Comment: How are you using domain masking? IFRAME or wildcard DNS?

Comment: if it's using an iframe, would it be worth checking the Referer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can get the url you want, but at the *client* side...

So, do this:

1. Get the browser's url by using a javascript call, like `window.location.href`.
2. Post that url to the server-side.

Cons:

1. This is a javascript dependent solution, it will not work with javascript disabled.
2. This is ugly as hell.

Pros:

1. You probably do not have any other option.